# psql server ssh tunneling authentication failure

Tags: postgresql, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a psql database on a remote server.

So I ssh tunnel into the remote server with port forwarding as below

```
ssh -L 7777:psqlServerHost.com:5432 me@remoteServerHost.com
```

Unfortunately using this method I'm unable to authenticate properly when I try the below command on separate terminal on my local

```
psql -h localhost -p 7777 -U user database
```

I would get

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
```

However if I were to directly ssh into me@remoteServerHost.com I would be able to connect to the database with the same credentials using the below command

```
psql -h psqlServerHost.com -U user database
```

I imagine this is probably a configuration file somewhere that I've missed, but I can't seem to find any similar queries that are helpful on the internet.

Comment: Are you sure about `psql -h psqlServerHost.com -U user database` connecting sucessfully? Do you have another PG running on `psqlServerHost.com` ?

Comment: @clamp Can you elaborate on what you mean by that connection connecting successfully? I was able to log in and do a select * from table with some results being displayed.

Comment: You don't specify a port, so you are connecting to 5432 on psqlServerHost.com. According to your ssh tunnel setup, your Database should be acessible on remoteServerHost.com:5432 and (via the tunnel) psqlServerHost.com:7777.

Comment: Hi @user1111111 did you find solution? We're also experiencing this.

Comment: @user1111111 any luck, i'm running into the same problem!